# parsing a huge file with awk and extracting a subset

Tags: awk

I have a huge file which looks like this

```
chr10   98072   1
chr10   98073   1
chr10   98074   1
chr10   98075   2
chr10   98076   2
chr10   98077   3
chr10   98078   5
chr10   98079   5
chr11   98080   5
chr12   98081   5
```

I have lot of entries for every chromosome. I only want to extract lines which have chr10. Since my file is very big, I used this command so as to extract only chr10 lines

```
awk '$1 ~ /^chr10$/{print}; $1 !~ /^chr10$/{exit}' cov.txt > subset.txt
```

Is this a good way to make awk not go through the entire file. My file is already sorted on chromosome

Thanks

Comment: Is `chr10` the first line in the file?  You have shown `chr11`, buit no `chr9`

Comment: chr10 is the first few lines after that it will never be chr10. It has been sorted that way

Comment: Just curious. How many chr10 entries are there?

Comment: These many entries 12947889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^chr10[^0-9]/ { p; b; }; q' cov.txt > subset.txt
```

This still assumes the `chr10` group is at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: `sed -n '/^chr10\>/{p;b};q'` is a little bit faster, but  not by much.

Comment: @Peter.O `\>` is a GNU `sed` extension.

Comment: @don_crissti Ah, you're right of course, `d` starts the next cycle, I missed that.  Ok, edited.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '$1=="chr10"{print; next}{exit}' cov.txt > subset.txt
```

---

Tests: Redirected to `/dev/null` for *12,947,909* `chr10` records plus a few more `chr11`, `chr12` and more to a total of *99,063,774* lines - outputs are all identical (same md5sum). The output line count = *12,947,909* -- ordered fastest to slowest:

steve: `awk '{ if($1 == "chr10") { print } else { exit } }' cov.txt >/dev/null`

```
real  0m5.963s
user  0m5.896s
sys   0m0.064s
```

Peter.O: `awk '$1=="chr10"{print; next}{exit}' cov.txt >/dev/null`

```
real  0m6.553s
user  0m6.484s
sys   0m0.068s
```

kos: `perl -pe '!/chr10/&&exit' cov.txt >/dev/null`

```
real  0m8.658s
user  0m8.545s
sys   0m0.112s
```

steve: `sed -n '/^chr10[^0-9]/ { p; b; }; q' cov.txt >/dev/null`

```
real  0m17.130s
user  0m17.077s
sys   0m0.052s
```

user3138373: `awk '$1 ~ /^chr10$/{print}; $1 !~ /^chr10$/{exit}' cov.txt >/dev/null`

```
real  0m18.621s
user  0m18.541s
sys   0m0.080s
```

Comment: `cut -f1 -d' ' cov.txt | grep -Fw 'chr10'` may be fastest, but will only output the first column (a long list of chr10). I think the OP needs all three columns....

Comment: Yes, I was just looking into that.. I had a feeling it was too good to be true (removed now) - and adjusted time results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, seemed a little quicker in my rudimentary test.  Avoids doing regular expression processing.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# wc -l cov.txt
34970568 cov.txt
[root@localhost tmp]# time awk '$1 ~ /^chr10$/{print}; $1 !~ /^chr10$/{exit}' cov.txt > subset.txt

real    0m23.897s
user    0m22.031s
sys     0m1.556s
[root@localhost tmp]# time awk '{ if($1 == "chr10") { print } else { exit } }' cov.txt > subset.txt

real    0m16.784s
user    0m14.731s
sys     0m1.661s
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Tried timing lcd047's sed approach too

```
[root@localhost tmp]# time sed -n '/^chr10[^0-9]/ { p; b; }; q' cov.txt > subset.txt

real    0m38.343s
user    0m36.609s
sys     0m1.546s
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Using plain old grep was fastest, even though it reads the entire file

```
[root@localhost tmp]# time grep "^chr10" cov.txt >subset.txt

real    0m6.546s
user    0m4.932s
sys     0m1.577s
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Would have thought grep -F to be faster again, but didn't appear to be.  Consistently over 7 seconds.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# time grep -F chr10 cov.txt >subset.txt

real    0m7.317s
user    0m6.109s
sys     0m1.173s
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Comment: If you can tell by hand that you wont have more than, let's say, thousand lines from the start, with chr10 and no more later, the fastest way should be `sed 1000q| ` and then the `grep` or anything else.

Comment: @ikrabbe: `head -n10000000` is *much* faster than `sed 10000000q`

Comment: @Peter.O I never measured that. That sounds as if the sed code could be improved somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

More efficiently, do it with `egrep`:

```
egrep '^chr10{space or tab}' cov.txt
```

Or if the contents are all similar to what you have shown,

```
grep -w chr10 cov.txt
```

Comment: At least on my system (Mint 17) the direct invocation of `egrep` is deprecated according to the `man` page. Use 'grep -E` instead.

Comment: This reads the entire file and takes proportionately longer as per the file size, which as the OP states, . is *huge*, it will take a much longer time to complete

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is sorted and as per [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/63486/user3138373) lines starting with `chr10` are always at the start of the file, using Perl:

```
< cov.txt perl -pe '!/chr10/&&exit' > subset.txt
```

This way the script will exit at the first occurence of a non-match.

A test of this run on a 1000000-matching-lines file stored in memory (obtained by appending the `chr10   98072   1` line 1000000 times to an empty file) runs in no time:

```
~/tmp$ < cov.txt wc -l
1000000
~/tmp$ time < cov.txt perl -pe '!/chr10/&&exit' > subset.txt

real    0m0.631s
user    0m0.624s
sys 0m0.004s
~/tmp$ < subset.txt wc -l
1000000
```